# Incorrect dependencies when upgrading MySQL from 5.7 to 8.0 on Debian 11

Tags: mysql, linux, debian

I am attempting to upgrade MySQL server from 5.7 to 8.0 on a Debian 11 machine after upgrading Jessie -> Bullseye.

Original MySQL 5.7 package was installed using basic `apt-get install mysql-server`.

I have read the "*Replacing a Native Distribution of MySQL Using the MySQL APT Repository*" [guide](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-apt-repo-quick-guide/en/#repo-qg-apt-replacing) however when following this guide I still have a conflict between mysql-common 5.7 and 8.0.

Here is an example of what I am doing:

```
# Delete old mysql installation and all related dependencies
> sudo apt-get remove automysqlbackup mariadb-common libmariadb3 sysbench mysql-community-client mysql-community-server mysql-common mysql-server mysql-client
> sudo apt-get autoremove

# Configure 8.0
> sudo wget https://repo.mysql.com//mysql-apt-config_0.8.24-1_all.deb
> sudo dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.8.24-1_all.deb  

# Update
> sudo apt-get update

# Install
> sudo apt-get install mysql-server

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mysql-community-server : Depends: mysql-common (>= 8.0.31-1debian11)
                          Depends: mysql-client (= 8.0.31-1debian11) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

For whatever reason if I install mysql-common it still installs 5.8. Purging it does not help.

```
> sudo apt list -a mysql-common
Listing... Done
mysql-common/unknown 8.0.31-1debian11 all [residual-config]
mysql-common/stable,now 5.8+1.0.7 all [residual-config]
```

```
> sudo apt-get install mysql-common

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  mysql-common
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 49 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/7,464 B of archives.
After this operation, 34.8 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-common.
(Reading database ... 82684 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-common_5.8+1.0.7_all.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-common (5.8+1.0.7) ...
Setting up mysql-common (5.8+1.0.7) ...
update-alternatives: using /etc/mysql/my.cnf.fallback to provide /etc/mysql/my.cnf (my.cnf) in auto mode
Scanning processes...
Scanning candidates...
Scanning linux images...

Running kernel seems to be up-to-date.

Restarting services...
 systemctl restart containerd.service

No containers need to be restarted.

No user sessions are running outdated binaries.
```

The only "solution" I could find is to install it manually from the deb:

```
wget https://repo.mysql.com//mysql-apt-config_0.8.24-1_all.deb
tar -xvf mysql-apt-config_0.8.24-1_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i mysql-common_8.0.31-1debian11_amd64.deb
```

After which `apt-get install mysql-server` works. However it seems hacky and not a proper way to do it at all.

What am I doing incorrectly here?

Comment: show what happens when you try to install just mysql-common?  do you have any apt settings that would make it prefer the stable 5.8 over the unknown 8.0.31 mysql-common?

Comment: @ysth It basically installs 5.8, I updated the original post to show the output. I don't believe I have any apt settings that would make it prefer the stable 5.8, is there any way to check why it does that?

Comment: I don't remember how that works, but it's unlikely if you haven't mucked with the apt config.  the other possibility I'd guess is you have something installed that makes it think it needs the old version.  try installing specifically the new version and see if it warns about dependency problems?  (see https://askubuntu.com/a/92021/276380 - should work on debian too)

Comment: have you considered just switching to mariadb? :)

Comment: @ysth Looks like I am able to install a specific version using `sudo apt-get install mysql-common=8.0.31-1debian11` and it works after that. It doesn't complain about anything. I am still not sure why it fails to do resolve that when doing `apt-get install mysql-server`.